# Automation of migration scripts creation for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database, database-schema, database-migration

We are using SQL Server database in our development process.

Sometimes one has to change the database schema (or add initial data) to match the needs and propagate this changes to the others.

Are there any tools that could generate such updates on the fly so that we can add them to our migration tool as separate SQL files?

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway

Comment: Liquibase seems to be a great deal! Thank you!